How to solve segmentation fault here and where it appears?
I'm making terminal game of life and when glider figure goes out of the map segfault 11 appears. Could you tell me where particularly this segfault appears and how to solve it?
my main.cpp looks like that:
#include "src/Board.hpp"

int main(){
    Board board(1);

    while(true){
        board.new_frame();
    }
}


my Board.hpp looks like that:
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#define square_size 20
#define yMax square_size
#define xMax square_size * 5 / 2

class Board
{
private:
    bool cells[yMax][xMax] = {{0}};
    int frame;
public:
    Board(){
        setup();
    }

    Board(int n){
        setup();
    }

    void setup(){
        cells[10][10] = 1;
        cells[10][11] = 1;
        cells[10][9] = 1;
        cells[11][11] = 1;
        cells[12][10] = 1;
        frame = 1;
    }

    void screenClear(){
        system("clear");
    }
    
    void wait(){
        using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms); 
    }

    int count_near(int y, int x){
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                if (j!=0 || i != 0){
                    if (y + i < yMax && y + i >= 0 && x+j < xMax && x+j >= 0){
                        if (cells[y+i][x+j] == 1){
                            cnt++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;
    }

    void output(int y, int x){
        if (cells[y][x] == 1){
            std::cout<<'*';
        }else{
            std::cout<<'.';
        }
    }

    void new_frame(){
        std::vector<int> changes;
        screenClear();
        for(int i = 0;  i < yMax; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < xMax; j++){
                output(i, j);
                int cnt = count_near(i, j);
                if (cells[i][j] == 1){
                    if (cnt < 2){
                        changes.push_back(i);
                        changes.push_back(j);
                        changes.push_back(0);
                    }else if (cnt > 3){
                        changes.push_back(i);
                        changes.push_back(j);
                        changes.push_back(0);
                    }
                }else{
                    if (cnt == 3){
                        changes.push_back(i);
                        changes.push_back(j);
                        changes.push_back(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout<<'\n';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < changes.size() - 2; i+=3){
            if (changes[i+2] == 0){
                cells[changes[i]][changes[i+1]] = 0;
            }else{
                cells[changes[i]][changes[i+1]] = 1;
            }
        }
        std::cout<<frame<<std::endl;
        frame++;
        wait();
        changes.clear();
    }
};

I googled and found out that seg fault 11 means accessing the memory space it is not allowed to space however my count_near function checks if y is within range of 0 to yMax and x is within range of 0 to xMax and it still output segmentation fault when the glider goes out of the map.

Start by using a debugger to catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens.

Don't use macros to define constants. Use constexpr int xMax = ... instead.

The problem was not where I or you thought it was. Good thing the debugger pointed me directly to it

Beware of macro definitions like #define xMax square_size * 5 / 2 -- this opens up to potential operator precedence problems depending on where xMax is substituted. If you must put an expression in a macro, you should wrap it in parentheses: #define xMax (square_size * 5 / 2)

Add #include <cassert> and add  assert(changes. Size() > 1); right before the line for (int i = 0; i < changes.size() - 2; i += 3). The run a debug build of the program and you'll understand what happens.

It is normal to expect the loop body to never be executed because 0 < 0-2 is false. Except that's not how C++'s unsigned type works, which is what trips up OP. And presumably they never turned on the warning that nags you about this...
